# Repromting in Alexa Skill

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

When building an Alexa skill with a custom Lambda endpoint, I've configured an intent called 'Hello'. Upon triggering this intent, I am expecting both a **message and a reprompt** message to be sent to the user. However, while the **initial** message is successfully displayed, the **reprompt** message doesn't appear. Additionally, I've ensured that the **shouldEndSession** parameter is set to **false**. The JSON response structure resembles the one outlined in the Alexa Skill Documentation.
[Documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/request-and-response-json-reference.html)

Output Json is same as like this:-

```
`{
  "version": "1.0",
  "sessionAttributes": {
   "supportedHoroscopePeriods": {
      "daily":true,
      "weekly": false,
      "monthly": false
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "outputSpeech": {
      "type": "PlainText",
      "text": "Today will provide you a new learning opportunity"
    },
    "card": {
      "type": "Simple",
      "title": "Horoscope",
      "content": "Today will provide you a new learning opportunity"
    },
    "reprompt": {
      "outputSpeech": {
        "type": "PlainText",
        "text": "Can I help you with anything else?"
      }
    },
    "shouldEndSession": false
  }
}`
```

Can someone help me regarding this? I've tried a lot but it doesn't work for me.
**Note:** I am not using Alexa Ask Library, I am working on a custom lambda not the one provided in Alexa Developer Console.

I am expecting when the Hello Event is triggered,
A **message** and a **reprompt** message should be displayed , but inn my case only the message is displayed not the reprompt message.

Sample Output:-

```
`**Me**: Alexa,Open MySkill.
**Alexa**: Hi, Welcome to My Skill.
**Me**: Hello , My name is Tushar
**Alexa**: Hello Tushar. ( Message )
**Alexa**: How Can I help you? (Reprompt-Message)
```

My **shouldEndSession** is set to **False** Only.
Any help on this ?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you say "displayed", implies (to me anyway) that you're using the Alexa app and not a "real" physical Alexa device.

If so then this is expected behaviour, the Alexa app doesn't do reprompts, it just waits for you to reply to the initial request.  Try it on a physical Alexa device and you should get your reprompt.

Edit:  The same goes for the Alexa test capability in the dev console.  It won't reprompt.

Comment: I'm testing it on Alexa Simulator in the Alexa Developer Console ,might  possible what you are saying is True, if this is true i think it's terrible :)

Comment: Yes, same thing, the simulator won't reprompt.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON response looks odd in that it is enclosed with a square bracket

```
'[
```

...and then closed by a parenthesis...

```
)'
```

Not sure why you have either of those in your response. I would remove them both. But, without seeing your code it's hard to say how this happened or why/if they are needed.

Comment: Sorry for the brackets , it might be due to the typo mistake..in actual the JSON format is correct.